# How to open a .int file with R?

Tags: r

Unfortunately I have to deal with a data file with .int file format. This has the effect of littering any search results with unrelated information about integers.

I can't figure out how to open this file in R. I have an example with the Julia language, shown below:

```
filename = "mnist_train.int"
open(filename) do f
  ...
end
```

But when I try to search for a similar function in R, I either find results about opening excel files, results for other languages, or results that deal with integers. Could someone please point me to some resources for dealing with this filetype?

Answer (score 1):

Because I am not sure about what the content type, guess you trying to open a binary file format.

You can have a look at `?readBin`